# Google Load Balancer creating frontend IP that differs from Compute Engine IP

Tags: https, routes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I have a single compute engine that I am trying to make accessible by HTTPS. I assigned it to a instance Group and added a port name that mapped to `443`. Then I created an HTTP(S) load balancer who's backend service connected to the instance and the port that I had set in the instance group. However, the IP address that the load balancer creates for the front end service is different to the external IP address of the instance.

So my question is, when I contact the frontend service IP address, will that route to the port `443` of the instance's IP address or is it expecting the external IP address of the instance to be the same as the fronend IP address of the load balancer.

Currently, my backend service is unhealthy, and I am suspecting this to be the probable reason. If not, are there any other steps I have to take to make my instance's IP address accessible via HTTPS other than setting a mapped port creating a load balancer with a backend service connected to that isntance and port?

Answer (score 0):

The load balancer should route to your compute engine instance(s) if you configured it properly, so first thing to check is your routing configuration. As a matter of fact, I would actually remove the static external IP address of the CE instance.

Also check your load balancing logs(explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring)) to see any errors.

Comment: The logs show `502` errors and the status details are `failed_to_pick_backend`. Do you know what this might mean by any chance? Also, what do you mean by "configured properly"? Thanks

Comment: can you access your backend directly via the ip address?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking correctly, when I try to access the frontend address I get a 502 error, but I can access the backend address (external IP of the instance).

Comment: go to vpc network -> firewall rules -> https and make sure incoming https traffic is allowed. also this video might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gn7pGQYkKnA

Comment: -  It is not expected the external IP address of the backend instance to be the same as the front-end IP address of the load balancer and there is no way you can assign the same external IP for both.
This HTTP response code ‘failed_to_pick_backend’ is generated when a GFE was not able to identify a viable backend instance to connect to.These errors indicate Health Checks are failing for all backends. cont..

Comment: - Health Checks fail can take place because the firewall rules[1] don't allow traffic from the Health Check IP ranges. Checking the customer's firewall rules.

- Make sure you configured the port of the health check same as the port of the backend on which the service is running. 

[1]https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#firewall_rules